# How to format django generated sitemap lastmod date?

Tags: python, django, sitemap

My sitemap generated this way:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.utils import timezone

class StaticViewSitemap(Sitemap):
    priority = 0.5
    changefreq = 'daily'

        def items(self):
            return ['index', 'contacts']

        def lastmod(self, item):
            return timezone.now()
```

As django docs [says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.lastmod), lastmod returns datetime. It renders sitemap.xml lastmod to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format and looks so:

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2016-10-19</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
       <loc>http://127.0.0.1/contacts</loc>
       <lastmod>2016-10-19</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

But how could I change lastmod format to ISO8601 (I need this: 2008-01-02T10:30:00+02:00) to get this:

```
<urlset>
    <url>
        <loc>http://127.0.0.1/index</loc>
       <lastmod>2016-10-19T00:25:00+03:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
       <loc>http://127.0.0.1/contacts</loc>
       <lastmod>2016-10-19T00:25:00+03:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

I've played around making custom 'formats' path as said [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/formatting/#creating-custom-format-files) (Django format localization) but did not found which setting should I change to get appropriate date format.
Thanks.

My urls.py:

```
...

sitemaps = {
    'static': StaticViewSitemap
}

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    ...
]
```

Comment: How do you generate your sitemap? Post your `urls.py` and any custom sitemap templates (if any).

Comment: I've added an update.

Comment: You should write a custom template, use the appropriate datetime format and include that template in your `urls.py`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#template-customization for details.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In built-in sitemaps template you have `<lastmod>{{ url.lastmod|date:"Y-m-d" }}</lastmod>`

You need to override template and fix the current format to ISO-format, more information right here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#template-customization

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('custom-sitemap.xml', views.index, {
        'sitemaps': sitemaps,
        'template_name': 'custom_sitemap.html'
    }),
    path('custom-sitemap-<section>.xml', views.sitemap, {
        'sitemaps': sitemaps,
        'template_name': 'custom_sitemap.html'
    }, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]
```

The quick link to all the format codes here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date